# scrapy crawlspider is not following next links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to gather news releases from the Italian national police. The problem I have having is that the scraper is not following the "next" links, even though I have a rule set to find the "next" or in Italian "Successiva" button and follow that link.

Here is my code.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from items import ScrapyCrimeScraperItem
from string import replace

class ItalyScraper(CrawlSpider):
name = 'italy_crawler_test'
allowed_domains = ['poliziadistato.it']

start_urls = [
    'http://www.poliziadistato.it/archivio/category/1298/2015/',
    'http://www.poliziadistato.it/archivio/category/1298/2015/9/'

]

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('http://.*/articolo/view/*.....')), callback='parse_article', follow=False),
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("/html/body/div[@class='container'[1]/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-md-6 col-md-push-3 padding0']/div[@class='trecolonne']/div[@class='center']/div[@class='bar']/ul[@class='paginazione']/li/a[contains(""@title,""'Successiva')]",)), follow=True))

# def generate_article_links(self, response):
#     for href in response.css('a'):
#         url = href.extract()
#         yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_article)


def parse_article(self, response):
    self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
    item = ScrapyCrimeScraperItem()
    item['city'] = response.selector.css('h1').extract()[0]
    item['country'] = 'italy'
    item['site_link'] = response.url
    item['article_link'] = response.url
    item['article_raw_text'] = self.remove_carriage_returns(response.selector.css('.resetfont '
                                                     'p').extract(

    )[0])
    item['article_raw_date'] = response.selector.css('.data').extract()[0]
    item['article_translated_text'] = ''
    item['article_translated_date'] = ''
    item['article_raw_markup'] = ''
    item['crimes'] = ''
    item['locations'] = ''
    item['dateformat'] = ''
    item['reserved1'] = ''
    item['reserved2'] = ''

    yield item


def remove_carriage_returns(self,item):

    return(item.replace("\n", " "))
```

I looked through some other responses to a similar question, but I am using the explicit `follow=True` on the second rule. Do I need a callback to generate a new request--or should not the follow variable take care of generating that new request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just messed up the quotes inside the XPath expression. Use a simpler one instead:

```
//ul[@class="paginazione"]/li/a[contains(@title, "Successiva")]
```